# How to style KendoUi Grid with boolean filter

Tags: filter, kendo-ui, grid, styles, boolean

Grid filter works as it should with any column. The only issue I've with styling Boolean data type column (see img).

[image]

Any Idea what may be missing?

```
        editable: true,
        columns: [
            { field: "kid", title: "OEM", type: "string" },
            { field: "dealerDId", title: "S.No", type: "string" },
            { field: "emailSubject1", title: "Subject" },
            {
                field: "isAdminViewOnly",
                title: "Is Admin View",
                template: "#: isAdminViewOnly ? 'Yes' : 'No' #",
                type: "boolean",
                filterable: {
                    messages: {
                        info: "Filter By Admin View:", 
                        // when filtering boolean numbers
                        isTrue: "Is Admin View", 
                        isFalse: "Is NOT Admin View",
                        style: "max-width:100px;"
                    }
                }
            },
```

}.......

Answer (score 2):

Fond it. one of my custom CSS classes was overwriting k-xxx class style